# Fetch value from a row by looping with certain groupby condition in Pandas

Tags: python, loops, iteration, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
uid date        value
573 2019-09-01  0.0
573 2019-09-23  22.0
557 2019-08-20  0.0
557 2019-08-25  5.0
557 2019-09-05  11.0
556 2019-08-24  0.0
556 2019-09-05  12.0
550 2019-08-27  0.0
550 2019-08-29  2.0
550 2019-09-11  13.0
532 2019-07-29  0.0
532 2019-07-31  2.0
```

I need to get the **second value** for each user (which means **22.0** for user **573**, **5.0** for user **557**, and so on).

I am new to python and can't get the idea of groupby iterrows or else. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure the data is sorted as you expect with:

```
df = df.sort_values(['uid', 'date'])
```

Then to get just the second row of each worker (the one before is the same `uid`, but the one before that is not the same `uid`) use:

```
df[(df['uid'] == df['uid'].shift()) & (df['uid'] != df['uid'].shift(2))][['uid', 'value']]
```

Comment: Wow it's the exact result I expected! Thank you very much